# assets_audio_player Crash after wrong url

Tags: flutter, exception, try-catch

Is work when the URL is available, the problem is when URL down make a long time ~1min to start another media.
I try to exit the Future after 4 seconds that print the warning and the app stay frozen
for ~1 min.

How I can handle this exception and avoid stopping the application?

```
Future<void> selectStation(Station item) async {
 Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
  
  try {
    await _assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio.liveStream(
      item.url,
    ));
    //_assetsAudioPlayer.onErrorDo = (handler) {
    //  handler.player.stop();
    //};
  } catch (e) {
    await _assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
    return;
  }
}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 4), onTimeout: () async {
  await _assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
  CoolAlert.show(
    context: context,
    type: CoolAlertType.error,
    text:
        "the station ${item.title} is no available, try later <timeout>!",
  );
  return;
});
}
```

log flutter :

```
W/MediaPlayer( 7297): Couldn't open https://test.tt/media.mp3
W/MediaPlayer( 7297): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://test.tt/media.mp3
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1690)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1520)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1437)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1174)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1146)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1170)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerImplemMediaPlayer$open$2.invokeSuspend(PlayerImplemMediaPlayer.kt:129)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
W/MediaPlayer( 7297):   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
I/OppoMediaPlayer( 7297): setDataSource(path, headers) isOppoCreate=false
V/MediaHTTPService( 7297): MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@ddd12ca): Cookies: null
I/OppoMediaPlayer( 7297): prepare() isOppoCreate=false
V/MediaHTTPService( 7297): makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@516bc3b
V/MediaHTTPService( 7297): makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@ddd12ca): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@516bc3b Cookies: null
E/MediaPlayerNative( 7297): error (1, -2147483648)
W/System.err( 7297): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
W/System.err( 7297):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7297):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1414)
W/System.err( 7297):    at com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerImplemMediaPlayer$open$2.invokeSuspend(PlayerImplemMediaPlayer.kt:185)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
I/OppoMediaPlayer( 7297): handleMediaPlayerError() mCurrentState=4
I/OppoMediaPlayer( 7297): handleMediaPlayerError() mNotUsingOppoMedia is true
I/MediaPlayer( 7297): prepare failed ,throw IOException to app
I/OppoMediaPlayer( 7297): release() isOppoCreate =false
D/OppoMediaPlayer( 7297): closeFd()
V/MediaPlayer( 7297): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer( 7297): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
D/MediaPlayer( 7297): _release native called
D/MediaPlayer( 7297): _release native finished
W/System.err( 7297): com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerFinder$NoPlayerFoundException
W/System.err( 7297):    at com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerFinder._findWorkingPlayer(PlayerFinder.kt:70)
W/System.err( 7297):    at com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerFinder._findWorkingPlayer(PlayerFinder.kt:88)
W/System.err( 7297):    at com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerFinder$_findWorkingPlayer$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
W/System.err( 7297):    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
W/System.err( 7297):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
W/System.err( 7297):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
W/System.err( 7297):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
W/System.err( 7297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7830)
W/System.err( 7297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7297):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
W/System.err( 7297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1040)
I/flutter ( 7297): PlatformException(OPEN, null, null, null)
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Player crashes when track file in invalid instead of giving some message.

https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer/issues/627

I change the plugin.